# Website is not scrollable after wrapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I want to create a overlay effect which dims everything except the header and the menu which opens if you hover over 'REPORTS' on the upper left corner.

Here the website: https://classymagazin.de/home/

It is working if I don't implement the overlay. But if I implement the overlay, the webpage isn't scrollable anymore. This is what I do to create the overlay:

```
jQuery( ".l-section.wpb_row" )
    .slice(2)
    .wrapAll( "<div id='overlayWrapper' style='position: relative;'/>");

jQuery( "#overlayWrapper" )
    .append( "<div id='overlayInWrapper' style='z-index: 90; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); overflow: auto; position: absolute; display: none;'/>");
```

Sadly, I need to do it with jQuery because it is an WordPress and Visual Composer generated website!

At the end it should look like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrvln.png)

Can you tell me where my error is and how I can fix that?
If you hover over 'REPORTS' that triggers a function which displays the overlay div `#overlayWrapper`.

Kind regards

Comment: perhaps you need to add `overflow-y:auto` to the style

Comment: Sadly not working....

Comment: I think you've misrepresented the problem - your site remains scrollable no matter what

Comment: Improve code format

Comment: What do you mean @alditis? And how could I fix the problem instead @Jaromanda X?

Comment: Console show: https://use.typekit.net/ghr2xom.js not found. You need it?

Comment: I have fixed it. Increased the slice by one!